for-each-group based on position
I have a XML with this format:
<rows>
    <row>
        <gSubAssetType>
            <mSubAssetType>
                <SubAssetType>126</SubAssetType>
                <sgSubAssCou>
                    <sSubAssCou>
                        <SubAssScno>0000205282</SubAssScno>
                    </sSubAssCou>
                    <sSubAssCou>
                        <SubAssScno>0002000294</SubAssScno>
                    </sSubAssCou>
                    <sSubAssCou>
                        <SubAssScno>0000203622</SubAssScno>
                    </sSubAssCou>
                </sgSubAssCou>
                <sgTest>
                    <sTest>
                        <Campo1>Value1</Campo1>
                    </sTest>
                    <sTest>
                        <Campo1>Value2</Campo1>
                    </sTest>
                </sgTest>
            </mSubAssetType>
            <mSubAssetType>
                <SubAssetType>125</SubAssetType>
                <sgSubAssCou>
                    <sSubAssCou>
                        <SubAssScno>0000209645</SubAssScno>
                    </sSubAssCou>
                    <sSubAssCou>
                        <SubAssScno>0000204835</SubAssScno>
                    </sSubAssCou>
                    <sSubAssCou>
                        <SubAssScno>0000208014</SubAssScno>
                    </sSubAssCou>
                    <sSubAssCou>
                        <SubAssScno>0000208854</SubAssScno>
                    </sSubAssCou>
                </sgSubAssCou>
            </mSubAssetType>
            <mSubAssetType>
                <SubAssetType>1</SubAssetType>
                <sgSubAssCou>
                    <sSubAssCou>
                        <SubAssScno>0000208850</SubAssScno>
                    </sSubAssCou>
                </sgSubAssCou>
            </mSubAssetType>
        </gSubAssetType>
    </row>
</rows>

I want to extract the data in this format:
SubAssetType_SubAssCou;1;2;0002000294;
SubAssetType_SubAssCou;1;3;0000203622;
SubAssetType_SubAssCou;2;1;0000209645;
SubAssetType_SubAssCou;2;2;0000204835;
SubAssetType_SubAssCou;2;3;0000208014;
SubAssetType_SubAssCou;2;4;0000208854;
SubAssetType_SubAssCou;3;1;0000208850;
SubAssetType_Test;1;1;Value1;
SubAssetType_Test;1;2;Value2;

I want to extract the nodes that start with <s (<sSubAssCou> and <sTest>) keeping track of the position of the node inside the parent, and the position of the parent inside its parent. I could do this with some nested for-each, but I need to use also <xsl:result-document> to write the output to a file, and Saxon give an error when trying to output to the same document twice. So I am trying to use for-each-group, but I don't see how to keep the position of the node mSubAssetType for each sSubAssCou  Any ideas how I can do that?
This is the template I am using
<xsl:template match="rows">
    <xsl:for-each select="row/*[starts-with(name(),'g')]">
        <xsl:variable name="tablePrefix" select="substring(name(),2)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'m')]">
            <xsl:variable name="mvIndex" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'sg')]">
                <xsl:variable name="tableSubPrefix" select="substring(name(),3)"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'s')]">
                    <xsl:variable name="svIndex" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$tablePrefix"/>_<xsl:value-of select="$tableSubPrefix"/>;<xsl:value-of select="$mvIndex"/>;<xsl:value-of select="$svIndex"/>;<xsl:value-of select="./*"/>;
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

Which works fine, but if I change it to write to a file based on the table prefix and suffix using result-document, as follows:
<xsl:template match="rows">
    <xsl:for-each select="row/*[starts-with(name(),'g')]">
        <xsl:variable name="tablePrefix" select="substring(name(),2)"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'m')]">
            <xsl:variable name="mvIndex" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'sg')]">
                <xsl:variable name="tableSubPrefix" select="substring(name(),3)"/>
                <xsl:result-document href="t_{$tablePrefix}_{$tableSubPrefix}.txt" method="text">
                <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(),'s')]">
                    <xsl:variable name="svIndex" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$tablePrefix"/>_<xsl:value-of select="$tableSubPrefix"/>;<xsl:value-of select="$mvIndex"/>;<xsl:value-of select="$svIndex"/>;<xsl:value-of select="./*"/>;
                </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:result-document>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

Then it fails with this error

Error at xsl:result-document on line 14 of generic-extract-test.xsl:
XTDE1490: Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI:
file:/xxxx/t_SubAssetType_SubAssCou.txt
in built-in template rule
Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI: file:/xxxx/t_SubAssetType_SubAssCou.txt

It seems you cannot use the same result-document twice. So the question is how I group these nodes so I can process them grouped by the node name, but keeping the mvIndex and svIndex

Consider to show us the exact code you have plus the exact error you get.

Also currently supported versions of Saxon are 11 and 12 and these are XSLT 3 processors where you could for instance use accumulators to keep track of positions. And of course there is xsl:number.

I edited to show the code I tried and the error.

consider to edit the question to show how many result files you expect to create and how they should be named

Using xsl:result-document and xsl:number:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="gSubAssetType">
    <xsl:result-document href="SubAssScno.txt">
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//SubAssScno"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
    <xsl:result-document href="sTest.txt">
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//sTest/Campo1"/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="SubAssScno">
    <xsl:text>{local-name(../../..)}_{local-name(../..)},</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number count="mSubAssetType | sSubAssCou" level="multiple" format="1,1"/>
    <xsl:text>,{.}&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Campo1">
    <xsl:text>{local-name(../../..)}_{local-name(../..)},</xsl:text>
    <xsl:number count="mSubAssetType | sTest" level="multiple" format="1,1"/>
    <xsl:text>,{.}&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>

Online fiddle running Saxon HE 12.5 Java with CheerpJ 3 in the browser.
After you have edited your question with a changed code sample and some XSLT sample code I think, if the element names are not known but it is all about the certain prefixes in element names that you want code like
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="rows">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="row/*[starts-with(name(),'g')]/*[starts-with(name(),'m')]/*[starts-with(name(),'sg')]" composite="yes" group-by="substring(name(../..), 2), substring(name(), 3)">
        <xsl:result-document href="t_{current-grouping-key()[1]}_{current-grouping-key()[2]}.txt">
          <xsl:variable name="outer-keys" select="current-grouping-key()"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*[starts-with(name(),'s')]" group-by="node-name()">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
              <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:string">
                <xsl:number level="multiple" format="1;1" count="*[starts-with(name(),'m')] | *[matches(name(),'^s[^g]')]"/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:value-of select="string-join($outer-keys, '_'), $pos, *" separator=";"/>
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:result-document>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Sample fiddle.

Thank you!! this worked nicely. I had to adapt it for some other tweaks, but absolutely pointed me in the right direction. As for your comment about the files, in this example I would expect two files t_SubAssetType_SubAssCou.txt and
t_SubAssetType_Test.txt
